# Custom Angular Image Directive in Repeater Causes 404

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a custom Angular JS directive whose template includes an image that contains some expressions which reference scope variables. Something like:

```
scope:{s:'@'},
template: '<img src="{{s}}" width="200">'
```

This works fine, but when I put my directive in a repeater, I get a 404 in the console that looks something like:
`GET http://run.jsbin.io/%7B%7Bs%7D%7D 404 (Not Found)`

Here is a jsbin where I've replicated the behaviour in a simple (albeit contrived) example:
http://jsbin.com/lavozequ/4/edit?html,js,output

You can only see the problem if you look at the JavaScript Console (not the one from JSBin, the one from your browser).

I believe this is by design. I think the repeater builds the DOM tree before data binding it in order to increase performance. So, the first time through the browser is trying to fetch an unbound element which is a string that points to a non-existent image.

My question is, can I create a similar directive that avoids this 404?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're binding to `src`, use `ng-src` instead:

```
scope:{s:'@'},
template: '<img ng-src="{{s}}" width="200">'
```

Angular will parse the contents of `ng-src` *before* modifying the `src` element, thus avoiding the 404's.

For more info: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc

Comment: Awesome. Not sure how I missed that. But that's exactly what I needed. Thanks!

Comment: @BillSparks I made the same mistake, seems to be a part of learning Angular.